# Airflow with PostgreSQL bottleneck issues

Tags: postgresql, airflow, airflow-scheduler, azure-postgresql

I have set up **Airflow 1.10.10** with **Celery** as Executor, **Postgres** as result backend and sql alchemy connection, and **Redis** as broker/message queue.
I'm using one pod for each Airflow component (scheduler, webserver, broker and 1 worker) with 2 GiB of memory and 2 cores of CPU. My **Postgres** instance is **running in Azure with 2 CPU cores**.
The main issue is that whenever I start scheduling some of the example DAGs, the **CPU resource of Postgres** will hit **~95%** and the tasks will start to fail, cause of connection issues (like PID timeouts in the Scheduler or the "*FATAL: remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections*" error)
I've tried changing some of the pool parameters from sql alchemy in the *airflow.cfg* but still getting the issue.
**My question would be:** is a Postgres DB running in Azure, 2 CPU cores good enough for handling DAGS? What would be an appropiate set up? Or how can prevent Airflow of congesting Postgres? Thanks!